# Customer Validation ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having the same problem as someone else in this forum.  My validation control is not firing...and not sure where I have gone wrong.  Could someone please take a look and let me know what obvious error I have here...thanks

I have set up a customer validator in my aspx page using the following:

```
       <asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeNumber2TextBox" runat="server"
 Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeNumber") %>'Visible='<%# AllowEmployeeNumberEdit() %>' />

           <asp:CustomValidator ID="ValidateEmpNumber" runat="server" 
onservervalidate="ValidateEmpNumber_ServerValidate" 
    controltovalidate="EmployeeNumber2TextBox" 
    ErrorMessage="You Must Enter an Employee Number" Text="*" />
```

and the code behind:

```
  protected void ValidateEmpNumber_ServerValidate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs e)
  {
      int SiteCompanyID = System.Convert.ToInt32(Session["SiteCompanyID"]);
      SiteCompanyBLL SiteCompany = new SiteCompanyBLL();
      SiteCompanyDAL.SiteCompanyRow ScRow = SiteCompany.GetCompanyByID(SiteCompanyID);
      bool AutoGenerate = ScRow.AutoGenNumber;  // result returning true or false
      if (AutoGenerate == false)
      {
          if (e.Value.Length == 0)
          e.IsValid = false;
      else
          e.IsValid = false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is the code not being run at all, or is it just not validating?

Comment: For safety sake, could you show the control tag that is performing your submit?

Answer (score 0):

Is the validator in sync with the control that is doing the submit/postback? Also, there is no condition that allows it to be `true`.

How do you know it isn't firing?

Comment: I set up a break on the method and it never reaches it...When the field is left blank I get an error message from the DB.

Comment: Sounds like your program is breaking. Set a breakpoint at the very first line of your method: `int SiteCompanyID = System.Convert.ToInt32(Session["SiteCompanyID"]);
` and see if it hits that

Comment: Your method doesn't get the text from the textbox. Seems like it has nothing to do with validating that input, unless its in `GetCompanyById()`. Just a thought, try replacing the `<%#...%>` values with default values and see if that does anything if nothing else works.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, but I don't think at this point it is in the code behind....the validation method is not getting called at all...I have set a breakpoint right at the start of the method and it never hits it...This validation control is in an insert template on a form view.
Thanks and I will keep working on it.

Comment: @Steve Hmm, well that changes things. would you mind posting the code around the textbox and validator? the formview code?

Comment: OK...I found the answer to my problem with some help from another inquiry on the same issue. First, since my test was to see if the textbox was empty, I needed to add & specify an “ValidateEmptyText” property to true. Apparently it will not fire if the textbox is empty unless you add this property. Second, I had not change my 'CausesValidation' to ="True" on my sumbit button, so I appologize for that oversight.  Thanks for all the help and I hope this help others in the future.

Comment: @Steve Dockins That was the first thing I said haha "Is the validator in sync with the control that is doing the submit/postback?" Glad you were able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the OnServerValidate and ControlToValidate with the first letter of each word uppercase? Those properties may be case sensitive.

I was able to run a cutdown version of your code on my system.

Are you sure your Web.config is set to compile debug?:

<compilation debug="true">

Comment: Yes...I just tested and it didn't change the result.

Comment: This probably won't matter for your problem, but one thing I noticed, is that there is no space between your binding quote and the 'Visible=. Visible should have a space before it.

Comment: It just copied over that way...it is actually on a separate line, but thank you for that

Comment: Please see edit above. In my test I removed the databinding and hardcoded some values in the input element.

Comment: OK...I found the answer to my problem with some help from another inquiry on the same issue. First, since my test was to see if the textbox was empty, I needed to add & specify an “ValidateEmptyText” property to true. Apparently it will not fire if the textbox is empty unless you add this property. Second, I had not change my 'CausesValidation' to ="True" on my sumbit button, so I appologize for that oversight. Thanks for all the help and I hope this help others in the future.